# Response.BinaryWrite(TEXT) is causing Fortify/Checkmarx XSS error

Tags: vb.net, xss, fortify, checkmarx

This is a pretty straightforward situation.  We have a database table that has a VARBINARY(MAX) field, this field contains a text file.  On the .NET side the user can download the text file from the database.  It's just plain text and coming from a trusted source.  However, fortify/checkmarx complains about Stored XSS.  The code is pretty straightforward.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition, $"attachment;filename=FileToDownload.txt")
Response.BinaryWrite(datafromDB)
Response.[End]()
```

The vulnerability scan points to the Response.BinaryWrite() and complains of Stored XSS, of course this is silly considering it's coming from a trusted source.  However, I want to find a way to remediate this  Is there a way to filter out the "datafromDB" object or sanitize this before it hits the response.BinaryWrite.

Comment: you can tell your security team that this is a false positive. I agree that this shouldn't get flagged not because the source of data is trusted (there is always a potential risk of tampering) but instead, the content-type http header clearly shows that it will be downloaded as a text file (as opposed to an text/html where XSS would propagate)

Comment: Thank you, that was another thought I had. Since the response header was text HTML I don't see how malicious code can screw up notepad lol. The only other thing I was thinking was some way somehow clicking on the button to download the text would call some sort of code injection through the data stream. I don't believe it's possible with modern browser technology but just thinking